# where the table will be store values in Magento for attribute has 'static' backend_type

Tags: magento

I know that:
If attribute have `backend_type` is `int/varchar/datetime`, it's value will be store int corresponding table, for example:

```
backend_type        |value's table                 |
--------------------|------------------------------|
int                 |catalog_product_entity_int    |
varchar             |catalog_product_entity_varchar|
static              |catalog_product_entity_???????|
```

So, where the value's table for `static` `backend_type`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static` means the attribute is stored as a column directly in the entity table. For products, the table is `catalog_product_entity`.